# How to synchronize iCalendar with Outlook

Tags: windows, calendar, outlook, icalendar

I store my .ics calender on a webdav server. With Thunderbird/Lighning I can read *and* write the calendar. But how to deal with Outlook?

Outlook can only read the ics file remotely. Synchronization using google calender is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

For outlook 2016, you want to install icloud on your PC. Once it is installed, it will let outlook 2016 run an "add-Ins" "iCloud Outlook Add-in" to synchronize your ical with outlook in both way. This means you can modify your ical on either outlook or iphone. Then the system synchronizes both.

If it fails, try to close outlook 2016, open icloud, uncheck the calendar. hit 'apply'. Then check calendar again.

Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

Sync your Outlook calendar with iCal :-

1) On the Tools tab, click Sync Services.

2) In the left pane, select the Calendar check box.

3) Under Select the accounts to sync, choose the account or accounts that you want to sync   for the selected item type.

Note   The On My Computer account includes all Outlook items that are not synchronized with a Microsoft Exchange account.

4) On the Outlook folder to add new items to pop-up menu, choose the location in Outlook where you want new items to be saved. "New" items are those that are added first in a different application or device, and then synced to Outlook.

5) Close the Sync Services dialog box, and then on the confirmation message, click OK.

Depending on the size of your calendar, the sync might take some time to complete. You can close Outlook and the sync will still complete. For example, it will take time if you have a calendar that spans more than a year.

6) Open iCal and see that you Outlook Calendar information has synced.

You might have to close both Outlook and iCal and then reopen to see that the calendars are synced .

Comment: i do not have ical (Apple app), so i couldn't really follow you instruction. Especially step nr. 4 is quit unclear for me